# Is Java 7 JVM fully ready for production?

Tags: java, jvm, production-environment, java-7

Java 7 GA was released July 28 but there where some [Hotspot problems affecting loops to be miscompiled](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3349) (advised by some guys from the Apache Lucene & Apache Solr community).

I want to know if we're talking about a isolate bug or is better to wait a little longer.

Anyway, It is a workaround disable these optimizations in HotSpot (enabled by default) if performance is not critical. ?  I would love to see sample codes that cause this bug , because I haven't reproduce it yet.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: No it is not an isolated bug. There are plenty of bugs reported against Java 7 as there are any released software. Your best bet is to look through the bug list and check the high severity bugs. Then see if you can live with them. Also run your Unit and Integration tests through Java 7. You have those right? :)

Comment: @Andrew Finnell Appreciate your time, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if we're talking about a isolated bug or is better to wait a little longer.

That question is not objectively answerable:

- It depends on your circumstances; i.e. how critical problems in production would be to you and whether you can easily roll back.
- It requires people to *predict* the existence (or otherwise) of unreported / unpublicized bugs that would be a show-stopper *for you*.

The one thing we can predict with confidence is that there ARE other bugs in Java 7, just like there ARE bugs in Java 6 and earlier versions.